# .NET Unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurs when calling function from a C++ CLR DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll, c++-cli, clr

I have a C# application that uses a managed C++ DLL (CLR) of a class (let's call the class `ManagedProcessor`). When I am about to create an object of this class, I receive the following message from Visual Studio:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in Main.exe.
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

If I execute the application from the command line, I receive even less information, simply "Unhandled Exception."

Here is a simple example of how it is called:

```
class Program
{
        static void CallDLLFunction()
        {
            try
            {
                ManagedProcessor proc = new ManagedProcessor("C:/SomeFolder");                    
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Encountered exception: {0}...", e.Message);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Before calling DLL Function");

            CallDLLFunction();

            System.Console.WriteLine("Before calling DLL Function");                
        }
    }
}
```

// ManagedProcessor.h

```
public ref class ManagedProcessor
{
public:
    ManagedProcessor(System::String ^folder);
    void doSomething();

private:
    bool mFlag;
};
```

I have included all of the necessary dependencies of the DLL but it still gives me this error. FYI, the target .NET platform is 4.0 and the assemblies are x64. Also, the DLL also has references to some native C++ code.

This problem only occurred as we moved our code base from Visual Studio 2008 to 2010 and we used CMake to generate the VS 2010 projects (I ensured that the generate 2010 projects had the exact settings as their 2008 versions).

I would really like some help with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually this means your p/invoke signature is probably incorrect, but because you don't show the managed code, its difficult to tell you how to fix it. I'm guessing you don't use the managed string class as an input parameter, but its only a guess. Possibly something in the managed DLL has an incorrect managed->unmanaged call too.

Comment: I use the managed `System::String` class as the input parameter type. I'll update my question with a simplified example of the CLR class.

Comment: Try running it in a debugger and examining the exception as it happens. Or else do a try/catch in the C# code and output the entire exception ToString. That may lead you closer to where the problem is occuring.

Comment: That's the way unmanaged code fails.  The complete lack of a useful diagnostic and the zero odds you'll get a useful answer here largely explain why managed code is popular.  You'll have to enable unmanaged debugging to at least have *some* idea what might be going wrong.  Still having libraries that target the VS2008 runtime, thus now having two copies of the CRT in the process, is generally a good way to corrupt memory.  Ask for help from whomever in your team worked on the native C++ code, they will be very familiar with this kind of problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I already tried those things @TheUndeadFish. I was initially running the application from the command line but I only got the "Unhandled Exception" message. It's only when I ran it in Visual Studio I got the more "detailed" message above. At least I know that it is an access violation. But I don't know what's causing it.

Comment: @Hans Passant I worked on both the managed and unmanaged code and everything is set to use the VS 2010 runtime. This issue is blowing my mind. I ran into similar issues before but those were just caused by a missing reference or something simple. But that's not the case for this issue.

Comment: You should post some actual code. A [minimal, complete, verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Your "simplified example" doesn't have practically any code inside it. Do you have the source or pdb files for the c++/cli part you could use to debug it? Also, use `exception.ToString()` instead of `exception.Message`, because it will show much more information (like stack trace).

Comment: The simplified example was just for context because it's not actually a "code" problem per se.  Something wrong is happening when the dll is being loaded; an access violation to be exact. I need help understanding why it would happen.

Comment: Hans hinted to a plausible explanation: you may be loading two copies of the CRT, so take a closer look at this possibility - other than that, all we can say from your question is that you get an access violation somewhere in your unmanaged code.

Comment: The interface from any pure-code DLL and .NET must be done through memory management procedures. The code above is too much incomplete: are you refereing IntPtr to parameters? Are you using AllocHGlobal to pass parameters and get results from DLL? Are you allocating the necessary memory space between C#/C++ before call your DLL?  If not, the chances are zero to interface these two languages. I´m used to call VB.BET and ASMx64 and without these structures, you will have Exceptions like this.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. I'll take all of the comments into consideration. The funny thing is, if I convert the DLL into a C++/CLI application, it works. It just can't be used by a C# application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by simply removing the Boost thread library from the linker input of my C++/CLI project. For some reason, that particular library was causing some sort of memory corruption / access violation at runtime (or mixing of runtimes, not sure). As far as I know, the library was built for VS 2010, but I didn't generate it so I can't confirm that with 100% surety. It was a transitive dependency, meaning that it was included by CMake because it was a reference included by one of the directly referenced libraries of my project (default CMake behavior). I changed the CMakeLists.txt file for the dependent project so that its dependencies weren't included in the C++/CLI project by adding the **PRIVATE** keyword to the target_link_libraries CMake command and voila:

```
target_link_libraries(DependentTarget PRIVATE ${REQUIRED_LIBS})
```